# SignalR send vs invoke

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, asp.net-core-2.1

Using ie the javascript client I can either use

```
connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message)
```

or

```
connection.send("Send", message);
```

- what is the difference between the two ? when to use each ?
- as a side question, where is the SignalR javascript API documented ? all I can find is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to read the source code to see the difference between `send` and `invoke`.

`Send` returns a promise that is resolved when the client has sent the invocation to the server, or an error occurred. The server may still be handling the invocation when the promise resolves.

`Invoke` returns a promise that is resolved when the server has finished invoking the method (or an error occurred). In addition, the `Invoke` promise can receive a result from the server method, if the server returns a result.

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/7e832eeb27b25be51dade7ccfe557af6c8d98cfa/clients/ts/signalr/src/HubConnection.ts#L187)

The only official documentation I have found for the JS client was [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-2.1)